# Difference between class_weight and scale_pos_weight in LightGBM

Tags: classification, unbalanced-classes, boosting

I have a very imbalanced dataset with the ratio of the positive samples to the negative samples being 1:496. The scoring metric is the f1 score,and my desired model is LightGBM. I am using the sklearn implementation of LightGBM. I have read the docs on the class_weight parameter in LightGBM:

> class_weight : dict, 'balanced' or None, optional (default=None)
>               Weights associated with classes in the form `{class_label: weight}`.
>               Use this parameter only for multi-class classification task;
>               for binary classification task you may use `is_unbalance` or `scale_pos_weight` parameters.
>               The 'balanced' mode uses the values of y to automatically adjust weights
>               inversely proportional to class frequencies in the input data as `n_samples / (n_classes * np.bincount(y))`.
>               If None, all classes are supposed to have weight one.
>               Note that these weights will be multiplied with `sample_weight` (passed through the fit method)
>               if `sample_weight` is specified.

On using the class_weight parameter on my dataset, which is a binary classification problem, I got a much better score(0.7899) than when I used the recommended scale_pos_weight parameter(0.2388). Should I use the class_weight parameter or the scale_pos_weight parameter to balance the classes?

Comment: Cross-posted at https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/54043/55122